# How to find resources with label decorator's value in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an eclipse plugin in which I have used decorators to decorate my resources with different text as a prefix. Now I want to search these resources with the text which I have used while decorating the resources.

What I exactly want is to extend eclipse's open resource dialogue so that I can enter the text which I have used to decorate resources to find them.

So how could I achieve this...

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The Open Resource dialog is not really customizable.

The dialog class is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.OpenResourceDialog`. This extends `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` which contains most of the label providers and the like which you would have to change. However this class is not designed to be modified and would be hard to change.

`FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` in turn is derived from `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` which can be extended more easily, but you would have to duplicate a lot of code from `OpenResourceDialog` and `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog`.